# using jquery function to change tab selected

Tags: jquery

is it possible to add a .click event inside a function which is called when something happens.

for example if some one clicks a button other than the tab navigation that button function will change the select tab.

how can I add it to this function function() { }

Comment: what is the name of the tab you are using? there are many tab plugins available can you add the plugin link?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery UI for tabs then you can use the select method as given below:

```
.tabs( "select" , index)
```

HTH